# Jupyter missing menubar

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I've a problem when I updated notebook to Jupiter.
The menubar and tools are missing like in the [following image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S90sO.png).

I'm on Kubuntu14.04. I tried installing via different methods and version of python. Same for any browsers. No warnings when launching notebook.
Someone have the same problem on windows ([here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/8320)).

If you have any ideas.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed removing ipython and major part of Jupyter traces and reinstalling everything from anaconda.